# Output cache by User using session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have to increase the performance of my website. so i need to put the data in  Output cache in c# based on individual users using session.

Actually i am using GetVaryByCustomString in global.asax for assigning username to user param in output cache. but session is not working GetVaryByCustomString methods.

C#:-

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Dashboard")]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {}
```

Web.config:-

```
<caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="Dashboard" duration="86400" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="User" location="Server" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

Global.asax:-

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(System.Web.HttpContext context, string arg)
        {
            if (arg == "User")
            {
                if (this.Session != null)
                    // depends on your authentication mechanism
                    return "User=" + context.Session;
                //?return "User=" + context.Session.SessionID;
            }


            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
        }
```

session state not available in this context